# Firebase Cloud Function, how can I access parent data after onCreate event triggered?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My realtime database data looks something like this but doesn't always have the "alarmLevel" data.   I'm trying to setup a cloud function to monitor if "alarmLevel" is created and then access other data from within that node to give context to a push notification message.

```
    -caddata
        -CC00202022
            -agencyEventId: CC00202022
            -agencyEventSubtypeCode: 55-B-1
            -agencyEventTypeCode: 55
            -agencyEventTypeCodeDesc: Electrical Hazard
            -agencyId: 5-36
            -alarmLevel: 1 //creation of this data triggers .onCreate event
            -location: 123 Main St 
            -priority: 5
            -totalAssignedUnits: 1
```

My cloud function looks like this:

```
    exports.sendAlarmLevelNotification = functions.database.ref('/caddata/{agencyEventId}/alarmLevel').onCreate(async (event, context) => {
let updatedEventCC = context.params.agencyEventId

let title = ('Events');
let content = ('Alarm Level Increase For Event# '+ updatedEventCC +'.');

let badge = ('1');
var payload = {

    notification: {
        title: title,
        badge: badge,
        body: content,
    },
};
```

The trigger itself works as I intend. The rest of it kind of works because the context.params is the same as one of the values I need (agencyEventId) but I also need to get the value of 'agencyId' in the same node which is what I cant figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `event` would be better labeled as `snap` and is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.datasnapshot) (see [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)). That means you can use it to traverse up the tree and fetch data:

```
exports.sendAlarmLevelNotification = functions.database
  .ref('/caddata/{agencyEventId}/alarmLevel')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const parentSnap = await snap.ref.parent.once('value');
    const agencyId = parentSnap.child('agencyId').val();
    // ... do whatever you want with the data
  });
```